# Three.js OrbitControls - How to change mouse trigger sensitivty?

Tags: javascript, three.js, camera, orbitcontrols

I would like to give some leeway to the mouse drag before the `OrbitControls` event of rotating the scene triggers.

E.g: Click & Drag mouse 5px before rotating the camera, instead of instantly

*Sorry if question is not phrased correctly, I lack the proper terminology*

Comment: That’s not a feature that OrbitControls offers out of the box. But you could copy the source file, paste it into your project, and manually make the modifications you want.

Comment: That's unfortunate.. I think many would find a feature like that useful. Thanks!